# spring boot cant connect to cassandra database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra

i am using a spring boot quick start and want to establish a connection to a cassandra instance that is running on an ubuntu VM on the same machine,
i get this error when running the spring boot app

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

2018-11-08 18:00:10.671  INFO 12076 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on DESKTOP-OG0KPA1 with PID 12076 (C:\Users\omar_\Downloads\gs-spring-boot-master\gs-spring-boot-master\complete\target\classes started by omar_ in C:\Users\omar_\Downloads\gs-spring-boot-master\gs-spring-boot-master\complete)
2018-11-08 18:00:10.680  INFO 12076 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-08 18:00:10.966  INFO 12076 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@60dcc9fe: startup date [Thu Nov 08 18:00:10 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-11-08 18:00:12.701  INFO 12076 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'cassandraTemplate' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=cassandraConfig; factoryMethodName=cassandraTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [hello/CassandraConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=cassandraTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]]
2018-11-08 18:00:13.020  INFO 12076 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2018-11-08 18:00:13.112  INFO 12076 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2018-11-08 18:00:14.517  INFO 12076 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8087 (http)
2018-11-08 18:00:14.560  INFO 12076 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-11-08 18:00:14.561  INFO 12076 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2018-11-08 18:00:14.570  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin;C:\Users\omar_\Downloads\apache-maven-3.5.4-bin\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Users\omar_\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\omar_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\omar_\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\omar_\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.3-bin\apache-cassandra-3.11.3\bin;C:\Python27;;.]
2018-11-08 18:00:14.775  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-11-08 18:00:14.775  INFO 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3830 ms
2018-11-08 18:00:15.491 ERROR 12076 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cluster' defined in class path resource [hello/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean]: Factory method 'cluster' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
2018-11-08 18:00:15.522  INFO 12076 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-11-08 18:00:15.534  WARN 12076 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-11-08 18:00:15.560  INFO 12076 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-08 18:00:15.583 ERROR 12076 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at hello.CassandraConfig.cluster(CassandraConfig.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at hello.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf5637d0.CGLIB$cluster$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at hello.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf5637d0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bfd61920.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at hello.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf5637d0.cluster(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 122 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>



    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::actuator[] -->
        <!-- tag::tests[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-opengis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-wfs-ng</artifactId>
            <version>${gt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>3.11.3</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>3.6.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>



        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${cassandra-unit-spring.version}</version>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
            <!--<exclusions>-->
                <!--<exclusion>-->
                    <!--<groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>-->
                <!--</exclusion>-->
            <!--</exclusions>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>cassandra-unit-shaded</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${cassandra-unit-shaded.version}</version>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.hectorclient</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${hector-core.version}</version>-->
            <!--<exclusions>-->
                <!--<exclusion>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>-->
                    <!--<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>-->
                <!--</exclusion>-->
            <!--</exclusions>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${cassandra-driver-core.version}</version>-->
            <!--<optional>true</optional>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!-- end::tests[] -->
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cassandra-driver-core.version>3.6.0</cassandra-driver-core.version>
        <cassandra-unit-spring.version>2.1.9.2</cassandra-unit-spring.version>
        <cassandra-unit-shaded.version>2.1.9.2</cassandra-unit-shaded.version>
        <hector-core.version>2.0-0</hector-core.version>
        <guava.version>19.0</guava.version>
        <gt.version>18.0</gt.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>







        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

i have set up a cassandra.properties file setting the host and port and keyspacename, also there is a cassandra config java class that sets the connection parameters to connect to the cluster
here is the file:

```
package hello;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext;


@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {
    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(CassandraConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return environment.getProperty("spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        final CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("spring.data.cassandra.contact-points"));
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("spring.data.cassandra.port")));
        LOGGER.info("Cluster created with contact points [" + environment.getProperty("spring.data.cassandra.contact-points") + "] " + "& port [" + Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("spring.data.cassandra.port")) + "].");
        return cluster;
    }

//
//    @Bean
//    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
//        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster =
//                new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
//        cluster.setContactPoints("192.168.164.130");
//        cluster.setPort(9042);
//        return cluster;
//    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

//    @Bean
//    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping()
//            throws ClassNotFoundException {
//        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
//    }
}
```

what else am i missing ?

**EDIT** : it turned out that i had to change the rpc_address in the cassandra.yml file in the vm host from localhost to the vm ip address, so its exposed to external connections

Comment: From the obvious in your post, the problem is caused by  this line: `cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("spring.data.cassandra.port")));`. And that can be the case only if `environment.getProperty("spring.data.cassandra.port")` returns null. Just make sure that your port config entry is properly configured and accessible.

Comment: https://github.com/girdhar-singh-rathore/spring-boot-cassandra-integration

Comment: still gives the same error :                                                                                               Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerService';

Comment: Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.164.130:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.164.130:9042] Cannot connect))

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a lot of boilerplate code that Spring handles for you, as long as your application.yml has the following properties:

```
spring:
   data:
      cassandra:
         contact-points: 
         keyspace-name: 
         username: 
         password: 
         port:
```

and the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Spring will configure the connection for you, similar to Spring data for RDBMS.

You can then use the Cassandra Repository to query your tables:

```
@Repository
public interface YourRepository extends CassandraRepository<Item> {
    //
}
```

And entity:

```
@Table
public class Item {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
      name = "id"
      type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private UUID id;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
      name = "key", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String key;
    @Column
    private String data; 
    //Getter setters
}
```

Comment: Go to https://start.spring.io/ and add Cassandra as a dependency for a starter project

Comment: Ok you can remove your CassandraConfig class then as it is not needed. You only need @EnableCassandraRepositories anywhere in your app.

Comment: no i need it cuz by default it will try to connect to localhost:port , but my case is that cassandra is running on a vm with different ip not localhost

Comment: In your property file set the ip and port 
`spring:
   data:
      cassandra:
         contact-points: <vm ip>
         keyspace-name: 
         username: 
         password: 
         port: <vm port>`

Comment: it does not get it and still connect to localhost i dont know why

Comment: This needs to be in `src/main/resources/application.yml`

Comment: yes i tried it as application.yml and application.properties both didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

You spring.data.cassandra.port is missing or null. You can change to below code so that if it is not present then the code will use the default

```
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port: <cassandra port/9042>}")
private int port;
```

Comment: i have replaced it with this : @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster =
                new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("192.168.164.130");
        cluster.setPort(9042);
        return cluster;
    } still got this error : Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.164.130:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.164.130:9042] Cannot connect))

Comment: Looks like protocol version mismatch. Are your using the same Cassandra version's jar. I am adding my Cassandra configuration. Or you can call .setProtocolVersion(<int value>) to set the protocol version. Also adding my configuration class

Comment: Also please check the port on which Cassandra in listening. It may be different e.g. 9142

Comment: the port and the versions are correct, i double checked them

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;


/**
 * @author dpoddar
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.xxx.abc.reposiroty.cassandra")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxx.abc")
@Profile("cassandra")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {
    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(CassandraConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "agenthub";
    }


    @Override
    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        final CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("localhost");
        cluster.setPort(9042);
        //LOGGER.info("Cluster created with contact points [" + environment.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints") + "] " + "& port [" + Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.port")) + "].");
        return cluster;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: No dependencies. That is package to scan. Changed it

Comment: it still giving red error on AbstractAgentHierarchy and CassandraAgentHierarchyService, what are the packages or how to import ?

Comment: Those are mycustom musiness class. You can safely remove those classes. Updated the code.

Comment: Also, getKeyspaceName() should have your space name.